# Help with unique factorization domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $D$ be a unique factorization domain, and let $a,b,c\in D\setminus\{0\}$

Prove that:

(i) If $1_D$ is greatest common divisor of $a,b$ and  of $a,c$, then $1_D$ is a greatest common divisor of $a,bc$

(ii) If $a\mid bc$ and $1_D$ is a greatest common divisor of $a,b$, so $a\mid c$

(iii) Are the above statements true if $1_D$ is replaced by $u∈U(D)$?

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: (i)Hint: If p is a prime element of D and p|xy what can you conclude? Now suppose that p |a and p|bc (iiI)The notation is not standard. What is U(D)?

Comment: I'd say that U(D) is a standard notation for the units of D.